# Using rstan::rstan.package.skeleton to add to existing R package

Tags: r-package, stan, rstan

I've already used devtools to create my package skeleton, then added a bunch of R code, metadata, documentation, etc. I would like to use rstan within this package. I understand that rstan::rstan.package.skeleton creates a package skeleton to facilitate this. So what is the best practice for augmented an existing package with the structure necessary to use rstan from that package? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say to use `rstan.package.skeleton` to create the skeleton in a temporary directory and then copy the relevant stuff it creates into the package you created by devtools. This would include

- `cleanup` and `cleanup.win` in the root of the directory
- the `tools` directory
- the `exec` directory
- the `inst/chunks` subdirectory
- the `src` directory
- the `R/stanmodels.R` file
- the `DESCRIPTION` file in the root of the directory

For the `DESCRIPTION` file, you may just have to combine it by hand with whatever `DESCRIPTION` file you have currently.